# Firebase Dashboard doesn't show Price values

Tags: android, events, parameters, firebase, firebase-analytics

We are having some issues with Firebase inbuilt parameters not showing on dashboard:

```
    Bundle bundle = new bundle();
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRODUCT_ID, publication.getProduct().getId());
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRODUCT_NAME, publication.getTitle());
    bundle.putLong(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.QUANTITY, quantity);
    bundle.putDouble(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE, Double.valueOf(variation.getPrice()) * quantity);
    bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CURRENCY, "ARS");
    firebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.ADD_TO_CART, bundle);
```

And our dashboard is currently showing this for the add_to_cart event:

[image]

The price is showing as zero even though we are sending price information for each product. The currency is not showing, the same for the product name.
Any ideas of whats wrong? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FirebaseAnalytics.Param.PRICE should contain the raw price (not multiplied by quantity) and FirebaseAnalytics.Param.VALUE should be specified as the price * quantity.

The [API docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.Event.html#ADD_TO_CART) for ADD_TO_CART state "Note: If you supply the VALUE parameter, you must also supply the CURRENCY parameter so that revenue metrics can be computed accurately."

Comment: Thanks Steve, your changes work but I don't understand why. It should be the same for firebase analytics if the price is just the price or if its the price multiplied by the quantity, it will receive a double value just the same in either case.

Comment: Same problem here. I'm using the C++ SDK with both Android and iOS for testing. I'm supplying kParameterPrice as the raw price of the item, kParameterQuantity as the number of items, kParameterValue as raw price * quantity, and kParameterCurrency is "EUR", which AFAIK is a valid ISO-4217 currency code. I'm getting no pricing information in the Firebase Console whatsoever. In fact, all of the numeric values seem be getting ignored, including quantity. I've also tried supplying the numbers as both strings and int/double values, but with no effect.